# Zxing barcode scanner fragment crashes after some minutes

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am using a simple barcode scanner fragment from `zxingfragmentlib` on [github.](https://github.com/mitoyarzun/zxingfragmentlib)

It works well. But when I left the device in scanning mode, it crashed after 3 or 4 minutes.

Also the only (red-colored) things that I see in logcat are:

```
10-14 14:37:42.914: E/dalvikvm(11025): Unexpected opcode(263) with kInstrCanBranch set
10-14 14:37:42.914: E/dalvikvm(11025): VM aborting
10-14 14:37:42.914: A/libc(11025): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00002b11 (code=-6), thread 11033 (Compiler)
```

What is the problem and how can I fix that?

Thanks in advance!